# echarts4r moving the plot down to make room for the legend

Tags: r, echarts

Is there a way to move the plot down so that there is some space between the legend and the plot area?  Ideally have the chart area automatically spaced below the legend.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(50),
  y = rnorm(50, 10, 3),
  z = rnorm(50, 11, 2),
  w = rnorm(50, 9, 2)
)

df %>% 
  e_charts(x) %>% 
  e_line(w) %>% 
  e_line(y) %>%  
  e_line(z) %>%
  e_legend(orient = 'vertical', left = 0, top = 0)
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `e_grid` function to adjust the "grid" on which the graph is plotted.

```
library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame(
    x = seq(50),
    y = rnorm(50, 10, 3),
    z = rnorm(50, 11, 2),
    w = rnorm(50, 9, 2)
)

df %>% 
    e_charts(x) %>% 
    e_line(w) %>% 
    e_line(y) %>%  
    e_line(z) %>%
    e_legend(
      orient = 'vertical', 
      left = 0, 
      top = 0,
      selectedMode = "single" # might be of use
    ) %>% 
    e_grid(left = 100, top = 5)
```

Plenty more options in the grid can be found [here](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid)

Comment: Any chance you could update the "here" link above please. It's going to a 404 error. Thnx

Comment: Apologies, I've just updated, [here too](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid)